# How to bind a 1:many relation in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4, cocoa-bindings

I have a simple Core Data app with to model objects: employee and notes. Employees can have many notes (1:many), each note belongs to one employee (1:1). In the employee window I display a list (NSTableView) of employees on file using an NSArrayController. Clicking on an employee displays their details next to the list (name address, gender etc.). Now, I would also like to display a list (also NSTableView) of the notes on file for the selected employee. The list should display 2 attributes of each note on file: its topic and its entry date).

I tried to do the following: (1) bind the date column of the table to the Employee controller, controller key: selection, model key path: notes.date (2) bind the topic column of the Employee controller, controller key: selection, model key path: notes.topic

However this throws an exception (unrecognised selector).

How do I correctly bind the notes attribute of an employee to the NSTableView? Can it be done "directly" using cocoa bindings in IB or is additional code required to access the notes attribute of an employee before I can set up the bindings? I checked the data written by Core Data and this looks all good.

Many thanks for your help...

EDIT: here's the stack trace from the debugger...

> ```
> 2011-09-30 00:46:56.010 EmployeeDemo[3843:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSFaultingMutableSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10260b9c0'
> *** First throw call stack: (
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c654986 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8b040d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c6e05ae -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190
> 3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c641803 ___forwarding___ + 371
> 4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c641618 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
> 5   AppKit                              0x00007fff87c72648 -[NSTableBinder _visibleRowIndexesForObject:] + 267
> 6   AppKit                              0x00007fff87c72291 -[NSTableBinder observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 131
> 7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8dbb818a NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 387
> 8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8dbb21af -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 756
> 9   AppKit                              0x00007fff876f1f0b -[NSController _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 206
> 10  AppKit                              0x00007fff877fc5fc -[NSController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 847
> 11  AppKit                              0x00007fff879a1cf9 -[NSArrayController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 98
> 12  Foundation                          0x00007fff8dbb818a NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 387
> 13  Foundation                          0x00007fff8dbd9387 NSKeyValueDidChange + 486
> 14  Foundation                          0x00007fff8dc6834b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _didChangeValuesForKeys:] + 631
> 15  CoreData                            0x00007fff8e827543 _PFFaultHandlerFulfillFault + 3619
> 16  CoreData                            0x00007fff8e825bd8 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1592
> 17  CoreData                            0x00007fff8e825254 _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 212
> 18  CoreData                            0x00007fff8e8250d8 _sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 56
> 19  CoreData                            0x00007fff8e85bd3e -[NSManagedObject valueForKey:] + 222
> 20  Foundation                          0x00007fff8dbb479e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 348
> 21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8799ded5 -[NSArrayController _multipleValueForKeyPath:atIndex:] + 84
> 22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8799cfc9 -[NSArrayController _singleValueForKeyPath:] + 151
> 23  AppKit                              0x00007fff87704cfe -[_NSControllerObjectProxy valueForKeyPath:] + 77
> 24  Foundation                          0x00007fff8dbb4761 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 287
> 25  AppKit                              0x00007fff87704baa -[NSBinder _valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] + 654
> 26  AppKit                              0x00007fff87704894 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 171
> 27  AppKit                              0x00007fff87907352 -[NSValueBinder _referenceBindingValue] + 31
> 28  AppKit                              0x00007fff87907163 -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] + 647
> 29  AppKit                              0x00007fff87906e48 -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 303
> 30  AppKit                              0x00007fff8791ed0b -[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 43
> 31  Foundation                          0x00007fff8dbb818a NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 387
> 32  Foundation                          0x00007fff8dbb21af -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 756
> 33  AppKit                              0x00007fff876f1f0b -[NSController _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 206
> 34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8795e7a5 -[NSArrayController didChangeValuesForArrangedKeys:objectKeys:indexKeys:] + 120
> 35  AppKit                              0x00007fff879601bd -[NSArrayController setContent:] + 870
> 36  AppKit                              0x00007fff879a2664 -[NSArrayController(NSManagedController) _performFetchWithRequest:merge:error:] + 370
> 37  AppKit                              0x00007fff87bb149e -[NSObjectController(NSManagedController) fetchWithRequest:merge:error:] + 177
> 38  AppKit                              0x00007fff87bb1522 -[NSObjectController(NSManagedController) _executeFetch:didCommitSuccessfully:actionSender:] + 92
> 39  AppKit                              0x00007fff87d932e7 _NSSendCommitEditingSelector + 30
> 40  AppKit                              0x00007fff87a50246 -[NSController _controllerEditor:didCommit:contextInfo:] + 188
> 41  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff847df90a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
> 42  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff847e177a _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 308
> 43  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c5e9c0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1724
> 44  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c5e9216 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
> 45  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff871924ff RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
> 46  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87199c21 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
> 47  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87199aae BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
> 48  AppKit                              0x00007fff876de191 _DPSNextEvent + 659
> 49  AppKit                              0x00007fff876dda95 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
> 50  AppKit                              0x00007fff876da3d6 -[NSApplication run] + 463
> 51  AppKit                              0x00007fff8795852a NSApplicationMain + 867
> 52  EmployeeDemo                        0x0000000100001a62 main + 34
> 53  EmployeeDemo                        0x0000000100001a34 start + 52
> )
> terminate called throwing an exception
> ```

EDIT 2:

It seems that there's another problem which has to do with the underlying model. The notes for an employee are entered via a separate window with its own controller. It creates the new note and allows the user to set its properties (topic, body text). When the user presses the "Save" button the saveNote method is executed:

```
- (IBAction)saveNote:(id)sender {
[[self note] setValue: [[self topicField] stringValue] forKey: @"topic"];
[[self note] setValue: [[self textView] string] forKey: @"bodyText"];
[[self note] setValue: [self employee] forKey: @"employee"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
            //todo: add proper error handling
    NSLog(@"An error occurred while trying to save the memo");
}
[[self window] close];
```

}

When I step through this method the exception is actually generated when setting the relation between the note and the employee (3rd line).

Comment: “Unrecognized selector” doesn't mean “everything you just did was wrong”; it means “this very specific thing you did was wrong”. Exactly what that was is detailed in the rest of the message. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: I've added the stack trace to the question. I've tried several options to get this to work - also tried to bind an ArrayController to the notes attribute. This did not work. The notes attribute contains an instance of NSSet while the ArrayController requires an NSArray. Also, as pointed out below in your comment, one apparently cannot bind a table directly to an array.

Comment: From the stack trace, I'm guessing you're binding an array controller to an NSSet property (which, IIRC, is what to-many relationships always are in Core Data). Make sure you bind its `contentSet`, not its `contentArray`.

Comment: Ok thanks so far. There seems to be another problem lurking when I set the relation between a new note and an employee, which apparently causes the exception... (I'm asking a question in a question... not too sure whether that's proper site etiquettes. Apologies if it's not)

Comment: Is it the same exception, with the same stack trace? If it is, then you may have made progress but the problem in this question remains unsolved. If not, then that should go in a new question.

Comment: Yes, it's the same stack trace. I think my original question (the binding) is answered by the tutorial suggested by sosborn. The remaining problem now is "Why do I get the exception when setting the relation between the employee and the note?" as showm in the method above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an NSArrayController whose content is bound to the relationship. Then you bind the NSTableView content to the NSArrayController. From there you can do the columns.

*UPDATE*

This [tutorial from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html) might help you out.

Comment: You don't bind a table view's content. It's bound automatically when you bind the columns. Binding the table view's content yourself causes problems.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorial. That was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the behaviour described in my question has something to do with having a document based Core Date app or having a "plain" core data app (the check you place when you create a new project in XCode).

I found that when I choose a document based core data app, the above problems do not occur. When I develop the same app as a non-document core data app, binding the notes controller generates the stack trace as shown in my original question and the exception is thrown as soon as I add a note to an existing employee.

So, in all fairness this is just a part of the solution as my experience of Cocoa and XCode is not sufficient to explain why it will not work using the non-document based variant.